# Wagtail url prefix for a custom Page model

Tags: django, url, wagtail

This question is probably trivial, but I am unable to see a simple solution.

I have custom page model representing Post:

> class PostPage(Page):

I would like to make all instances of this model (all Posts) accessible only with url prefix

> /posts/

Example:

User creates new Post, the assigned slug will be

> awesome-first-post

What should happen is, that

> /awesome-first-post/

will result in 404, while

> /posts/awesome-first-post/

will display the post.

Note: I want this prefix only for the specific model Postpage. Other pages should be served directly from their slug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Wagtail, page URLs are formed from the list of slugs of the page's parent and ancestor pages, based on the page's position in the tree - the developer doesn't specify them directly. So, to get the URL `/posts/awesome-first-post/`, create a page with the slug `posts` (usually you'd create a dedicated `PostIndexPage` page model to serve as a listing page), and create the page `awesome-first-post` as a child of that one (by clicking the '+' icon next to the Posts page in the explorer listing view).

If you want to make sure that users only ever create `PostPage`s as children of the `PostIndexPage`, use a [`subpage_types` / `parent_page_types` setting](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.subpage_types), for example:

```
class PostPage(Page):
    # ...
    parent_page_types = ['PostIndexPage']
```